# Get sums of corresponding rows with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have:

```
a = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3])
b = np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2)
```

I want to calculate the sum of rows in `b` according to the corresponding ids defined in `a` (only sum the rows with same ids). So the output in this case would be `c` which has shape `4x2`.

```
c[0] = b[0] + b[1]
c[1] = b[2] + b[3] + b[4]
c[2] = b[5]
c[3] = b[6] + b[7] + b[8] + b[9]
```

How can I achieve this without a for loop? Does numpy have some fancy indexing method to achieve this more efficiently? Thanks.

Comment: `np.add.reduceat` might work

Comment: this is a great use case for `groupby` in pandas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.add.at`:

```
>>> out=np.zeros((4,2),int)
>>> np.add.at(out,a,b)
>>> out
array([[ 2,  4],
       [18, 21],
       [10, 11],
       [60, 64]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
a = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3])
b = np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2)
e = np.split(b, np.cumsum(np.unique(a, return_counts=True)[1])[:-1])
c = np.array(list(map(sum, e)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mask to exclude/include values to be added:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0,0,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,3])
b = np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2)

mask   = a[:,None]==np.arange(4)
result = np.sum(b[:,:,None]*mask[:,None,:],axis=0)
```

output:

```
print(mask*1)  # rows of b that will be added in each column 

[[1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1]]

print(result)  # result: 4 sums for each column of b 

[[ 2 18 10 60]
 [ 4 21 11 64]]

print(result.transpose()) # vertical representation:

[[ 2  4]
 [18 21]
 [10 11]
 [60 64]]
```